# Where does Azure keeps non-vm logs? Can them be downloaded programmatically?

Tags: azure

Azure keeps a bunch of VM (and cloud service) related logs in WAD* tables. The question is about actions which do not necessarily affect VMs. Say one deleted a Table Storage. Does Azure keep a log record about that? If yes, where? How to fetch them using a program/script?

Comment: Have you had a look under the **Operational Logs** of the **Management Services** tab (in the current portal - not the preview portal)?

Comment: Yep. Edited the question to make it clear I need access them programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Service Management REST API can be used to retrieve the operation logs programmatically.

**List Subscription Operations**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/gg715318.aspx